# How to find missing values?

Tags: r, knn, imputation

What are the techniques (such as KNN, Max likelihood) that I can use to find the missing values? 
I want to use R and trying to find a suitable technique to impute the missing values.

The sample data is shown below:

```
F1  F2  F3  F4  F5  Class
Good    20  5   7   Old Normal
Good    Missing 8   8   Old Normal
Good    15  10  10  Old Normal
Good    50  10  10  Old Normal
Good    70  10  10  Old Abnormal
Bad 20  5   7   Old Abnormal
Good    20  5   80  Old Abnormal
Good    85  100 100 Old Abnormal
Good    20  100 Missing Old Abnormal
Good    24  6   8.4 Old Normal
Good    12  9.6 9.6 Old Normal
Good    18  12  12  Old Normal
Good    60  12  12  Old Normal
Good    84  Missing 12  Old Abnormal
Bad 24  6   8.4 Old Abnormal
Good    24  6   96  Old Abnormal
Good    102 120 120 Old Abnormal
Good    24  120 72  Old Abnormal
```

[image]

Comment: See packages mice and Amelia and their vignettes and references.

Comment: In the function `read.table()` you can set `na.strings = "Missing"`

Answer (score 2):

Here are couple of codes that can help you with the analysis

#### If data has any NA or not

```
any(is.na(..name of data..))
```

#### Visualizing missing data

```
require(VIM)
aggr(..name of data..,plot = TRUE,bars=TRUE)
```

#### calculate percentage of NAs

create a simple function

```
propmiss <- function(dataframe) lapply(dataframe,function(x) data.frame(nmiss=sum(is.na(x)), n=length(x), propmiss=sum(is.na(x))/length(x)))
```

propmiss(..name of the data..)

#### Removing rows with more then 50 % values ( similar function for columns )

```
sparse.rows = c()
for (i in 1:nrow(clust.datatrain))  {
  if (sum(length(which(is.na(clust.datatrain[i,])))) > 0.5*ncol(clust.datatrain))  {
    sparse.rows = c(sparse.rows,i)
  }
}
length(sparse.rows)  #25
clust.datatrain = clust.datatrain[-sparse.rows,]
```

### imputation

#### KNN

```
require(DMwR)
train.1=knnImputation(clust.datatrain, k = 10, scale = T, meth = "weighAvg",
                      distData = NULL)
```

#### Using MICE ( multiple methods ) example of Bayesian linear regression below

```
require(mice)
xdash=mice(datafile,m=5,maxit=50,meth='norm',seed=500)
completedata=complete(xdash,1)
completedata
```

This all should be good for analysis and imputation !